# Database Denormalization for Performance Gains for SELECT reports

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, performance

**Note:** This question can be answered keeping `MySQL` or `MSSQL` RDMBS in mind

**Background:**

- Lets say you have a table named `records`. This table has 20 fields some of which are `VARCHAR(255)`.
- You have to run reports on two fields named `amount (FLOAT)` and `status (INT)`.
- Since one record can have only one status, it is kept in the same table.
- Table is indexed on `status` and `amount`.

**Situation:**

Indexing is working ok, even with more than 10 million records the response times on grouping based on those two fields are acceptable.
However as the data grows the efficiency of index is being reduced because RDBMS has to still parse through all those data subsets and not just parse those two fields. This results in slower and slower reports even with proper indexing.

**Question:**

Although amount has one to one relation with the record and it does not really make sense to put the amount and status in a separate table alongwith record id foreign key but, do you think that would make it more efficient even if it becomes less normalized?

**Why do I ask this question?**

Because it sounds like simple logic to me that if i have a separate table which contains a record id and corresponding amount then when i run some reports on amount and status then they will be much faster than the current setup Because the database has to now look at less data and less amount of data has to pass through the data buss etc and all those fields which were not needed for computing a report are not being parsed for data at the OS level. I know that when i run a report on amount and status then a databse won't care about other fields and value stored in them but nonetheless it still has to read all those data subsets in order to parse the records and at Disk level that still results in `reads`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a reporting query you are running and a create table output so we can see what your current indexes look like?

Comment: A couple of things you can try before denormalizing your database.  1) Move the fixed length fields to the front of the row and your varchars to the end of the row. 2) SELECT on just status and amount, rather than the whole row.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks, its very interesting to know that it matters if those variable length fields are moved to the end

Comment: @Ø HankyPanky Ø: I don't know how much it matters, but a database engine can precalculate a displacement past a fixed size column, whereas the database engine has to calculate the displacement past a varchar field based on the content length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denormalizing the database gives you a very good performance(response time) gain but you have to compromise space usage.

in your case i think `Partitioning` the database horizontally can do some increase in performance.

1. Range – this partitioning mode allows a DBA to specify various
   ranges for which data is assigned. For example, a DBA may create a
   partitioned table that is segmented by three partitions that contain
   data for the 1980's, 1990's, and everything beyond and including the
   year 2000.
2. Hash – this partitioning mode allows a DBA to separate data based on
   a computed hash key that is defined on one or more table columns,
   with the end goal being an equal distribution of values among
   partitions. For example, a DBA may create a partitioned table that
   has ten partitions that are based on the table's primary key.
3. Key – a special form of Hash where MySQL guarantees even
       distribution of data through a system-generated hash key.
4. List – this partitioning mode allows a DBA to segment data based on
       a pre-defined list of values that the DBA specifies. For example, a
       DBA may create a partitioned table that contains three partitions
       based on the years 2004, 2005, and 2006.
5. Composite – this final partitioning mode allows a DBA to perform
               sub-partitioning where a table is initially partitioned by, for
               example range partitioning, but then each partition is segmented
               even further by another method (for example, hash).

[taken from mysql dev](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html)